# Will a Spark job write to or read from the local file system?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, bigdata

For a Spark job, its input and output are all in HDFS. However, I am wondering that, during the execution of a Spark job, is there anything that needs to be written to or read from the local file system?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add to your save function the path like this: `file:///path/you/want`

Comment: Thanks! What is the "save function"? Also, I am considering a normal Spark job without specific configuration.